# Dependent Resident permit in Netherlands for spouse with German Resident Permit(Student)

Tags: germany, netherlands, dependent-visa

I'm an Indian national with Highly Skill Migrant permit working in the Netherlands for over 5 years now. My fiancé (also Indian) has a German student resident permit till 2023 as she just completed her masters.

She plans to stay with me after our marriage in March in the Netherlands and find job opportunities in the Netherlands. I read somewhere she can stay in the Netherlands for max 90 days.

- Meanwhile, while staying in Netherlands, can she apply for a dependent visa?
- Does this also mean she needs to surrender/cancel her German resident permit if the dependent visa is to be applied?
- Can the VISA process/resident card process be done and collected in Germany/Netherlands as well? (Hope we don't have to travel back to India to just get her resident permit)